# Weird monitor behavior

Tags: display, power-supply, power

I had a power outage in my neighbourhood last night. My PC is working normally but my monitor (LG) isn't. This isn't the first time this had happened. Before, when power outages happened, my monitor would show no sign of life, but a few days later it would work like nothing happened. Does anybody have any idea how to fix this? Or at least explain me what is going on?

Btw, I already checked my PC for damage and it's null (I've connected it on to a TV which is also LG).

Answer (score 1):

I would leave the monitor unplugged for a couple hours, push the power button a few times to try and drain any remaining power in the monitor. I would also check another monitor/cable with your PC just to confirm it isn't those things. If it continues to not turn on it is possible it has taken damage from a high-voltage kick.